# SQL: Invalid Column name works in one query but not the other

Tags: sql

I can get the 'Name' Column in one query but when combined with that of another I get an "Invalid column name" output.

```
select Name
from Tb_Product;
```

Here I get the expected output of the product 'Name'  and all is well...

```
select City, Name
FROM Tb_Supplier Stbl, Tb_Product Ptbl
WHERE Stbl.City = 'Chicago'
```

But, here the 'Name' column is invalid...

Comment: I would be surprised that this query would what you want, even if you were to fix the immediate problem. Your code does a cartesian product of the two tables. Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text, so one can look into this and provide a comprehensive solution.

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different database products. Which one do you use?

Comment: To help people answer your question, it really helps if you include what database system you are using (MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, etc), the table structures, example data, and what error you are receiving - see see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

try fully specifying the name:

```
select City, Ptbl.Name
FROM Tb_Supplier Stbl, Tb_Product Ptbl
WHERE Stbl.City = 'Chicago'
```

also, you do not have a join condition between the supplier and the product...  this query will likely not give you the results you are expecting.

Comment: That fixed it thanks. Could you explain why that fixes it?

Comment: my guess was that each table contained a Name column - and the parser can't decide which one you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue is that *name* is a **reserved keyword**:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-N

DBMSes or programming languages have reserved keywords that should be avoided for naming objects. They may still work but yield unexpected results, or produce confusing error messages that are not so easy to debug.

It's possible to get around this by qualifying the column name with a table prefix as suggested by Randy, or enclosing the column name between brackets ([]). But it's best to avoid overly generic object names, as there is a chance that you will sometimes stumble upon reserved keywords. If in doubt - check the list. Read it in full and bookmark it :)

The tags for the question are not consistent though, because they mention both SQL Server and MySQL, unless you really work with both. The lists of reserved keywords vary from one platform to another.